# How to keep a Google Chrome extension pop-up open?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am looking for a way to keep a google chrome extension open, when a user clicks off.

I have read through every stack overflow question on this topic, and all of them seem to say this is not possible or they provide a deprecated approach.

Before you say this is not possible, please note, I have in fact seen this behavior in-action on a live chrome extension (loom.com video recording extension does this).

So a follow-up question to mine, is how does the loom chrome extension keep their chrome extension widget/contents open when a user clicks off?

The reason I need this behavior, is I am creating a tutorial chrome extension, that shows people how to navigate a site.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not possible with the standard popup. Loosely speaking, what you've seen is a different thing: a DOM element inside the page or a separate window (either created via chrome.windows.create or by an external nativeMessaging utility).

Comment: Phil, why did you close my question? That resource you linked doesn't answer question. I shared specifically in my question details that i read those and it doesn't answer my question

Comment: My comment above explains all technically possible solutions. The linked duplicate topic contains examples for those solutions. That info is still valid as the extensions API is mostly unchanged for the past ~10 years.